# Problems with using java.lang.ThreadGroup in Java

Tags: java, bluej, pmd

I am creating a game using BlueJ environment developed by Kent University. There is a PMD plugin for checking code´s validity. After checking code of my Start class I run into a problem - PMD displays this warning message:

```
Avoid using java.lang.ThreadGroup; although it is intended to be used 
in a threaded environment, it contains methods that are not thread safe
```

The warning is reported to be on this line:

```
System.setOut(new java.io.PrintStream(System.out,true,characterSet));
```

There is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Start
{
    static Game game = new Game();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
           String characterSet=System.getProperty("myGame.encoding");
           if (characterSet != null) {
               System.setOut(new java.io.PrintStream(System.out,true,characterSet));
           }
        }
        catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // unsupported encoding
        }

        String name;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);     
        System.out.println("Enter Your nickname. \n ");              
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("\n Hello " + name + ", I am glad to meet You \n ");

        new TextInterface().play();
    }
}
```

I have read some already answered questions on this topic, but in most cases it was some kind of bug in the PMD plugin or something unrelated. I am new to Java and this seems to be its advanced part. How can I fix this error please?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be definitely a bug on PMD.

1. What version of PMD are you using? Bare in mind the latest release is 5.7.0. If not using it, update it and recheck.
2. If the issue persists with PMD 5.7.0, report the issue on [PMD's issue tracker](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues)